# Preprocessor operation with sum as parameter

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

Right, so I'm trying to understand C preprocessor and man it is a hustle.

I have a simple

```
#define Square(x)(x*x)
```

and I need to find out what `Square(5+2)` returns upon calling. As a newbie in this area, I immediately thought it would show `49`, but lo and behold it came back with `17`. And for some good minutes I tried to find out how the hell could that play out like that.

Can someone explain this to me? As comprehensive as possible would be good, since I am a bit dumb.

Comment: `Square(5+2)` will be expanded as `5+2*5+2`, which is 17 (BODMAS rule).

Comment: I can't believe there is no duplicate!

Comment: Of course there is...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Preprocessor macros in C do a direct symbol substitution.  So this:

```
Square(5+2)
```

Turns into this:

```
(5+2*5+2)
```

While is evaluated as:

```
(5+(2*5)+2)
```

Which is 17.

You should always parenthesize macro arguments to prevent issues like this:

```
#define Square(x) ((x)*(x))
```

Then the above invocation will expand to:

```
((5+2)*(5+2))
```

Comment: To be more precise, according to you define, it will expand to ((5+2)*(5+2)) :)

Comment: @jaudo Correct.  Edited.

Comment: Small detail explanation: the outermost parentheses are not needed for safety of the argument(s) themselves (`x`), but to protect the resulting expression if reused in another expression; *bad* example: `#define X2(X) (X)+(X)`, used as `X2(2) * X2(2)` similarly failing (8 instead of 16) as question's original code...

Answer (score 0):

While [dbush](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1687119/dbush) explained correct [parenthesising in macros](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51505959/1312382) already, there is a much safer alternative: inline functions:

```
static inline int square(int x)
{
    return x*x;
}
```

It is not *always* possible to convert macros into an inline function (e. g. for logging, if you want to use `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` macros), or it is, but you have to define multiple different versions (one for int, one for double, ...), so inline functions aren't the Holy Grail either, but as arguments are evaluated *before* the function is entered, you are safe from the type of error you made and additionally, you are prevented from multiple evaluation of the argument(s) (which sometimes can even result in undefined behaviour:

```
int x = 7;
// inline function:
int y = square(x++); // safe
// macro:
int z = Square(x++); // expands to z = (x++)*(x++) which is undefined behaviour!
```

So if you can have inline functions without unreasonable code overhead, prefer them...